# Can't access files listed by serve-index in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I have the following very simple server written for Node.js with Express:

```
'use strict';

 const express = require('express');
 const serveIndex = require('serve-index');

 express()
   .use(serveIndex(__dirname + '/public'))
   .listen(1024);
```

While this does display the contents of the directory just fine, when I click on any file listed, I get an error message along the lines of `Cannot GET /example.png`. What is going wrong?

Comment: you need to provide the full error message

Comment: That is, essentially, the full error message. What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened a bug and they finally fixed the documentation:

https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index/blob/master/README.md

The tl;dr version:

```
var express    = require('express')
var serveIndex = require('serve-index')

var app = express()

// Serve URLs like /ftp/thing as public/ftp/thing
// The express.static serves the file contents
// The serveIndex is this module serving the directory
app.use('/ftp', express.static('public/ftp'), serveIndex('public/ftp', {'icons': true}))

// Listen
app.listen(3000)
```

You have to mount the `express.static` middleware first.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. When I click on a file, it returns, `Cannot get` error. When I click on a **folder** it works as fine, so I have came up with this solution.

```
var express    = require('express');
var serveIndex = require('serve-index');

var app = express();

app.use('/', serveIndex('public/', {'icons': true}));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){

})
app.get('/text.txt', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/text.txt");
})

app.listen(1024);
```

This program will find the files and folders that are located in my `./public/` directory and send them as responses. When I click on a file from the responses, which is in `./public` directory, the program runs `app.get('filename', ..)` function. As we did not have this code down below, it returned `Cannot get` error.

Here is the solution, you will check if the client `get`s the link, and if he/she does we will send the **file** as a **response**. Just little bit of more coding here.

```
app.get('/text.txt', function(req, res){  //text.txt is the file name here
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/text.txt");
})
```

Comment: This gives me the very same problem as I described above. Did you try running your example?

Comment: @Sadiq I have edited the answer and ran the program, it works fine now.

Comment: @Sadiq please let me know if you were able to do it too

Comment: @Sadiq also if you want to use css from default too you could use `inspect` from the default page copy and paste `style` from there

Comment: Well that's a start I guess but I want to serve more than one file from the directory. The official documentation kind of works but I'm wondering whether this can be done in purer Express form.

Comment: you could create a server and do a `switch` on `req.url` which is less code,

Comment: @Sadiq I don't think you can do it with pure `express` you need to define `app` to use the service.